# Google Sheets Script for passing a few cell values on one sheet to new sheet row

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I have looked and looked and tried to adapt some scripts but am stuck.

Can someone help/show me how to add a collection of specific cells on one sheet and populate the next available row on a second sheet with these values? Please. This is what I have:

```
function AddToDB2() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var target = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName("PurchaseOrder");
  var targetSheet = target.getSheetByName("DataBase");

  var range = ss.getDataRange();
  var values = range.getValues();
  var date1 =  values[1][6]; //these values are collected from multiple cells not in a specific row or col
  var po =     values[2][6];
  var vendor = values[7][0];
  var shipto = values[7][3];

  //this was for testing that the values were grabbed correctly.
  var data =  [date1,po,vendor,shipto]; 

  // I don't think this part is even close
  var lastRow = targetSheet.getLastRow()  
  var rowData = values[0]
  var newData = []
  for(n=1;n<lastRow;++n){newData.push(rowData)}
  targetSheet.getRange("C2:H"+lastRow).setValues(newData);

}
```

---

This is the other way I came up with:

```
function addToDB() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var target = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName("PurchaseOrder");
  var targetSheet = target.getSheetByName("DataBase");

  var sourceRangePO = sourceSheet.getRange("G3");
  var poValues = sourceRangePO.getValues();

if(poValues != "") {

  var sourceRangeDate = sourceSheet.getRange("G2");
  var targetRangeDate = targetSheet.getRange("A2");
  var dateValues = sourceRangeDate.getValues();
  targetRangeDate.setValues(dateValues);

  var sourceRangePO = sourceSheet.getRange("G3");
  var targetRangePO = targetSheet.getRange("B2");
  var poValues = sourceRangePO.getValues();
  targetRangePO.setValues(poValues);  

  var sourceRangeVendor = sourceSheet.getRange("A8");
  var targetRangeVendor = targetSheet.getRange("C2");
  var vendorValues = sourceRangeVendor.getValues();
  targetRangeVendor.setValues(vendorValues);

  var sourceRangeShipTo = sourceSheet.getRange("D8");
  var targetRangeShipTo = targetSheet.getRange("D2");
  var shipToValues = sourceRangeShipTo.getValues();
  targetRangeShipTo.setValues(shipToValues);

  targetSheet.insertRowAfter(1);
  Browser.msgBox("Your PO has beed saved!");

  }

else { Browser.msgBox("Please enter a PO number"); }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were very close. Try this. I was a little confused by your setValues C:H. You only have 4 values to set. I set them in D-G. You can adjust as needed.

```
function AddToDB2() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName("PurchaseOrder");
  var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("DataBase");

  var range = sourceSheet.getDataRange();
  var values = range.getValues();
  var date1 =  values[1][6]; //these values are collected from multiple cells not in a specific row or col
  var po =     values[2][6];
  var vendor = values[7][0];
  var shipto = values[7][3];
  var data =  [date1,po,vendor,shipto]; 
  var lastRow = targetSheet.getLastRow()  
  var newData = []
    for(n=0;n<data.length;++n){newData.push([data[n]])}
  var rng =targetSheet.getRange(lastRow+1,1,1,4) // Col A-D
  rng.setValues([newData]);
 }
```

Comment: Ohhh so close. Thank you very much! Can you comment on the block of code I added under the original questions code? I was wondering if that would be more or less efficient than what you helped me with. For me, the location of the data on the sheet doesn't matter so I came up with that to do the same thing.

Comment: My way is more efficient. Dealing with arrays generally is. I changed my code to write to A-D like yours. If you do use your code, change setValues to setValue. If I helped, please approve my answer. Thanks. If you want to share your spreadsheet, I might have some more ideas. I have worked with a lot of POs.

Comment: Much appreciated! I will certainly go with the original code you helped me with. It would be great if you could take a look at it. I also am working on the   "search" function to look up and populate the PO. So far so good with that... I think. What is the best way to share it with you? Thanks again.

Comment: To share click the share button in the upper right corner of the spreadsheet. Choose share with anybody with a link. Copy the share link and paste that link in your comment.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lQ8yOiGo12kYgvP81gWCB2cA0OEqEzWEBROoCTPMs_k/edit?usp=sharing     Thanks!!

Comment: I have your spreadsheet. I have made a copy and shared with edit. We can use it to communicate. They don't like these threads on SO to get to long. I will add a sheet for notes. I am working on a few ideas, but I have not added them yet. The link is https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_VGUKjqg86s9V9xmkmrdkrwxbkPz47pOoGuVaZnEebs/edit?usp=sharing